# Generate string of yesterday’s date-time in ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, simpledateformat

In Android, I am using `java.util.Calendar` to get yesterday date in format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'`. For example if today is `31 May 2017`, I want to get yesterday date as `2017-05-30T00:00:00Z`.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// Date End = yesterday
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
Date dateEnd = calendar.getTime();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'");
this.dateEndStr = formatter.format(dateEnd);
```

I am expecting output to be `2017-05-30T00:00:00Z`. But it gives me `2017-05-30T12:00:00Z`.

What is wrong here? Is it TimeZone related? My timezone is `GMT/UTC + 08:00 hour`.

Comment: print ***dateEnd***... that shows the correct date

Comment: In the future, write a title that summarizes the core of your Question specifically. I did so for you this time.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a mistake in your `SimpleDateFormat`.

You use `hh` for the hours, but that shows the one based hour of AM/PM.

These are the relevant symbols (from [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

- `H`  Hour in day (0-23)
- `k`  Hour in day (1-24)
- `K`  Hour in am/pm (0-11)
- `h`  Hour in am/pm (1-12)

You want this : `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

***Remark***

You say your timezone is +08:00 hours, and you calculate the date using that timezone, however you format it as if it's in the Zulu timezone (which has an offset of +00:00)

***BONUS***

In Java 8 all this Calendar manipulating goes away :

```
ZonedDateTime yesterday = ZonedDateTime.now().with(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY, 0).minusDays(1);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
dateEndStr = formatter.format(dateEnd);
```

Comment: Thanks! `HH` fixed my problem :D

Comment: It is obviously correct that it is incorrect to give Z as time zone on a time at zone offset +8. I also agree that one should prefer the Java 8 solution, it’s much clearer and more convenient. The desired format is ISO 8601, the default in Java 8, so you may use either `Instant.toString()` or `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`, this is simpler and clearer than building your own formatter. And, as the question shows, less errorprone. :-)

Comment: Also the Java 8 date and time classes have been [backported to Java 6 and 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). There is really no good reason why you shouldn’t prefer them for this task.

Answer (score 5):

I am probably answering more than you asked about, but now you have asked, why not take all of it? I see two or three things wrong with your code. bowmore in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278173/5772882) has touched on all three already, but I think a couple of them can be made a little clearer still:

1. Yes, the first and most serious is time zone related. You need to decide, and you should make explicit in your code, which time zone you use. And it is incorrect to give Z as time zone on a time at zone offset +08:00. Z is for Zulu time, another name for UTC.
2. In your format pattern, you should use capital `HH` for hour of day.
3. You should prefer the modern date and time classes, in principle always, but *at least* for a case like this. With these you won’t be able to make the errors you did with the oldfashioned `SimpleDateFormat`.

### Time zone

Time zone is crucial to your task. You need to decide whether yesterday’s date in UTC (as your requested output says), in `GMT/UTC + 08:00` or, say, in the the JVM’s current time zone (which can be changed at any time while your program is running). This snippet uses UTC:

```
this.yesterdayAtStartOfDay = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .minusDays(1)
    .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
```

Running it just now, the result is

```
2017-05-30T00:00:00Z
```

Instead of the last line of the snippet, you may use the even simpler:

```
    .toString();
```

This gives the same result because `atStartOfDay()` gives a `ZonedDateTime` with time zone Z, and its `toString()` method gives the ISO 8601 string you requested.

If you want yesterday’s date in another time zone, in the first line of the snippet (and only the first line) use for example `ZoneOffset.ofHours(8)`, `ZoneId.of("Asia/Hong_Kong")` or `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as time zone.

In case you are using Java 6 or 7, to use the modern date and time classes you need to get [the *ThreeTen-Backport* library](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Even though I always think twice before introducing an external dependency, I recommend this one warmly for your task.

That back-port is further adapted for Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Answer (score 0):

To subtract days, you should use:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
```